# Packing UV's With Projected View Unwrap

Tags: uv

I have this roof that I unwrapped using the "Project from view" unwrap. My problem is, when I repack the UV's again in the UV editor, then it messes up my roof again. Any idea how to automatically pack the UV's while keeping "Projected from view" UV's correct?

[image]

Thank you for any help  :)

Comment: When you pack the islands, Blender only packs what is selected in the UV window. So you could select everything except for the roof parts, then do the packing. It should not touch the roof UVs.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't really work. It packs everything but since the roof wasn't selected, it repacks over the roof. So then you still need manually pack the roof again